# Excel formula can start with?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

All

I am using excel for financial calculations .

Excel is having formula auto complete feature and generally any excel formula starts with  '=' equal to symbol .

But when ever I type @or + or - operator as a first character and start typing alphabets excel suggesting formulas ..!

Can any one explain what's the use of + or - or @ as a first character of formula ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's your question?  I always type "@" whenever I want to start a formula like "@sum(...)".  Isn't that expected behavior?  Is there some specific problem you're having?

Answer (score 2):

Starting a formula with + is a compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3.

Starting a formula with @ must be a localized enhancement, it does not work with my English Excel with English regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a formula with an @ seems to work for me using English regional settings - it gets converted to an = once I hit enter, however. I have never heard of this before - perhaps it's another, more obscure, legacy feature?